# How to find position of substring in another column of dataframe using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark scala DataFrame with two columns, text and subtext, where subtext is guaranteed to occur somewhere within text. How would I calculate the position of subtext in text column?

Input data:

```
+---------------------------+---------+
|           text            | subtext | 
+---------------------------+---------+
| Where is my string?       | is      |
| Hm, this one is different | on      |
+---------------------------+---------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---------------------------+---------+----------+
|           text            | subtext | position |
+---------------------------+---------+----------+
| Where is my string?       | is      |       6  |
| Hm, this one is different | on      |       9  |
+---------------------------+---------+----------+
```

Note: I can do this using static text/regex without issue, I have not been able to find any resources on doing this with a row-specific text/regex. Found an answer here that works with pyspark. I am looking to use similar solution in scala.
[How to find position of substring column in a another column using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65831272/how-to-find-position-of-substring-column-in-a-another-column-using-pyspark)

Comment: Did you resolve your issues based on answer?

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ 

val df = Seq(
  ("beatles", "hey jude"),
  ("romeo", "eres mia")
).toDF("name", "hit_songs")

val df2 = df.withColumn("answer", locate("ju", col("hit_songs"), pos=1))
df2.show(false)
```

Gets first find position from or equal to the pos you specify, not all occurrences.

**UPDATE**

You can adapt to use col as opposed to literal, that goes without saying. However, the stuff on Columns and using locate etc. does not work well. E.g.

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("answer", locate(col("search_string"), col("hit_songs"), pos=1))
```

this does not work. I find this aspect hard to explain, but I cannot cast col search_string to string as we have this Column aspect to consider.

So, this is what you need: a UDF reverting to Scala functions:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._  
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column 
import spark.implicits._
 
val df = Seq(("beatles", "hey jude", "ju"), ("romeo", "eres mia", "es") ).toDF("name", "hit_songs", "search_string")
 
def ggg = udf((c1: String, c2: String) => {
   c2.indexOf(c1)  
} )
 
  
df.withColumn("value",ggg(df("search_string") ,df("hit_songs"))).show(false)
```

Note you may add 1 to result as it starts at 0.

Interesting to note the contrast with this question and answer: [Pass dataframe column name as parameter to the function using scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66554598/pass-dataframe-column-name-as-parameter-to-the-function-using-scala)

In any event:

```
 df.withColumn("answer", locate(df("search_string"), col("hit_songs"), pos=1))
```

does not work.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, creating an UDF works. I was more interested to know if there's way to use column in locate function. We can pass column in the location function in PySpark. I haven't found a way in Scala yet.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to try these out. Really appreciate it.

Comment: No you can't with Scala. Believe me I looked. I find it hard to explain but it is not possible afaics. To do with Column. If u google on SO u will see that. Th3 answer is correct.

Comment: No is also an answer.